# SOLR edismax with BF function on non existing fields

Tags: solr, edismax

I would like to apply negative boost on the documents which does not have specific fields. But its not working and results the same boost value for the document with and without that field.Any pointers would be of great help.

`bf=if(not(exists('image-small_string')),0,-500)`

Answer (score 0):

The [answer is to boost those documents that *do not* match your query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F), instead of trying to apply a negative boost to those that do.

To boost documents that has a specific field, you can use `bq=foo:[* TO *]^5` (and adjust the boost factory to match the behaviour you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks ! After some more research i found that it is possible to do negative boost by giving a negavtive number as a boost. As bf is additive boost, it will then substract the give boost and works as a negative boost. for example bf = if(not(exists(img_product_string)),-100,0)